# Publish .net core app from VS 2017

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, publish, visual-studio-2017

I am creating a new solution under Visual Studio 2017 Community Edition, it's mainly a .net core web application.

It works perfectly, no problem at all, but we want to deploy it to a Debian machine and to be self contained, so we added the runtime identifiers to the project. So far so good, the problem comes when we want to publish the application (to a directory) for any of the platforms we have, there is no option to specify the target platform and the publish files created are just the .net assemblies, no native modules.

Of course if we use `dotnet publish -r (platform)` it works as expected, it creates the correct platform files and everything seems to be ok, but is very annoying to have to go to command line to compile it.

So the question is, how can be published a self-contained application for a concrete platform using Visual Studio 2017? Is it even possible or this is still missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently VS2017 won't do this so you have to drop to the command line and run this.

```
dotnet publish -c release -r ubuntu.14.04-x64
```

Obviously replacing ubuntu for your debian flavour.

Also this is in my csproj file and you might need it too.

```
<OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
```

Comment: You may be able to write a build script to run post build.

Comment: It seems the OutputType is no more needed, If I publish with dotnet it already creates an executable.

Comment: I think a post build script is currently your best option until this gets sorted.

Comment: Yes, it seems that's the only option, a shame.

Comment: I'm accepting the previous answer as Joel was the first on answering and commented more or less the same, I'm also upvoting your answer.

Comment: Yes, I misread your question initially to be honest and didn't see your bit about already using the -r parameter on the command line app.

Answer (score 2):

You can update your project file csproj to add runtimeIdentifier:

```
<RuntimeIdentifier>win7-x86</RuntimeIdentifier>
```

replace win7-x86 with your desired runtime.

Even though in the publish screen it says Runtime: Portable, it does seem to generate a stand alone version.

[image: visual studio 2017 publish screen]

Result in explorer:

[image: explorer publish result]

### Executed command by vs2017

```
 C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Roslyn\csc.exe /noconfig /unsafe- /checked- /nowarn:1701,1702,1705,2008 /nostdlib+ /platform:x86 /errorreport:prompt /warn:4 /define:TRACE;RELEASE;NETCOREAPP1_1 /errorendlocation /preferreduilang:en-US /reference:C:\Users\Joel\.nuget\packages\microsoft.csharp\4.3.0\ref\netstandard1.0\Microsoft.CSharp.dll /reference:C:\Users\Joel\.nuget\packages\microsoft.visualbasic\10.1.0\ref\netstandard1.1\Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll /reference:C:\Users\Joel\.nuget\packages\microsoft.win32.primitives\4.3.0\ref\netstandard1.3\Microsoft.Win32.Primitives.dll /reference:C:\Users\Joel\.nuget\packages\system.appcontext\4.3.0\ref\netstandard1.6\System.AppContext.dll /reference:C:\Users\Joel\.nuget\packages\system.buffers\4.3.0\lib\netstandard1.1\System.Buffers.dll /reference:C:\Users\Joel\.nuget\packages\system.collections.concurrent\4.3.0\ref\netstandard1.3\System.Collections.Concurrent.dll /reference:C:\Users\Joel\.nuget\packages\system.collections\4.3.0\ref\netstandard1.3\System.Collections.dll /reference:C:\Users\Joel\.nuget\packages\system.collections.immutable\1.3.0\lib\netstandard1.0\System.Collections.Immutable.dll /reference:C:\Users\Joel\.nuget\packages\system.componentmodel.annotations\4.3.0\ref\netstandard1.4\System.ComponentModel.Annotations.dll /reference:C:\Users\Joel\.nuget\packages\system.componentmodel\4.3.0\ref\netstandard1.0\System.ComponentModel.dll /reference:C:\Users\Joel\.nuget\packages\system.console\4.3.0\ref\netstandard1.3\System.Console.dll /reference:C:\Users\Joel\.nuget\packages\system.diagnostics.debug\4.3.0\ref\netstandard1.3\System.Diagnostics.Debug.dll /reference:C:\Users\Joel\.nuget\packages\system.diagnostics.diagnosticsource\4.3.0\lib\netstandard1.3\System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource.dll /reference:C:\Users\Joel\.nuget\packages\system.diagnostics.process\4.3.0\ref\netstandard1.4\System.Diagnostics.Process.dll /reference:C:\Users\Joel\.nuget\packages\system.diagnostics.tools\4.3.0\ref\netstandard1.0\System.Diagnostics.Tools.dll /reference:C:\Users\Joel\.nuget\packages\system.diagnostics.tracing\4.3.0\ref\netstandard1.5\System.Diagnostics.Tracing.dll /reference:C:\Users\Joel\.nuget\packages\system.dynamic.runtime\4.3.0\ref\netstandard1.3\System.Dynamic.Runtime.dll /reference:C:\Users\Joel\.nuget\packages\system.globalization.calendars\4.3.0\ref\netstandard1.3\System.Globalization.Calendars.dll /reference:C:\Users\Joel\.nuget\packages\system.globalization\4.3.0\ref\netstandard1.3\System.Globalization.dll /reference:C:\Users\Joel\.nuget\packages\system.globalization.extensions\4.3.0\ref\netstandard1.3\System.Globalization.Extensions.dll /reference:C:\Users\Joel\.nuget\packages\system.io.compression\4.3.0\ref\netstandard1.3\System.IO.Compression.dll /reference:C:\Users\Joel\.nuget\packages\system.io.compression.zipfile\4.3.0\ref\netstandard1.3\System.IO.Compression.ZipFile.dll /reference:C:\Users\Joel\.nuget\packages\system.io\4.3.0\ref\netstandard1.5\System.IO.dll /reference:C:\Users\Joel\.nuget\packages\system.io.filesystem\4.3.0\ref\netstandard1.3\System.IO.FileSystem.dll /reference:C:\Users\Joel\.nuget\packages\system.io.filesystem.primitives\4.3.0\ref\netstandard1.3\System.IO.FileSystem.Primitives.dll /reference:C:\Users\Joel\.nuget\packages\system.io.filesystem.watcher\4.3.0\ref\netstandard1.3\System.IO.FileSystem.Watcher.dll /reference:C:\Users\Joel\.nuget\packages\system.io.memorymappedfiles\4.3.0\ref\netstandard1.3\System.IO.MemoryMappedFiles.dll /reference:C:\Users\Joel\.nuget\packages\system.io.unmanagedmemorystream\4.3.0\ref\netstandard1.3\System.IO.UnmanagedMemoryStream.dll /reference:C:\Users\Joel\.nuget\packages\system.linq\4.3.0\ref\netstandard1.6\System.Linq.dll /reference:C:\Users\Joel\.nuget\packages\system.linq.expressions\4.3.0\ref\netstandard1.6\System.Linq.Expressions.dll /reference:C:\Users\Joel\.nuget\packages\system.linq.parallel\4.3.0\ref\netstandard1.1\System.Linq.Parallel.dll /reference:C:\Users\Joel\.nuget\packages\system.linq.queryable\4.3.0\ref\netstandard1.0\System.Linq.Queryable.dll /reference:C:\Users\Joel\.nuget\packages\system.net.http\4.3.0\ref\netstandard1.3\System.Net.Http.dll /reference:C:\Users\Joel\.nuget\packages\system.net.nameresolution\4.3.0\ref\netstandard1.3\System.Net.NameResolution.dll /reference:C:\Users\Joel\.nuget\packages\system.net.primitives\4.3.0\ref\netstandard1.3\System.Net.Primitives.dll /reference:C:\Users\Joel\.nuget\packages\system.net.requests\4.3.0\ref\netstandard1.3\System.Net.Requests.dll /reference:C:\Users\Joel\.nuget\packages\system.net.security\4.3.0\ref\netstandard1.3\System.Net.Security.dll /reference:C:\Users\Joel\.nuget\packages\system.net.sockets\4.3.0\ref\netstandard1.3\System.Net.Sockets.dll /reference:C:\Users\Joel\.nuget\packages\system.net.webheadercollection\4.3.0\ref\netstandard1.3\System.Net.WebHeaderCollection.dll /reference:C:\Users\Joel\.nuget\packages\system.numerics.vectors\4.3.0\ref\netstandard1.0\System.Numerics.Vectors.dll /reference:C:\Users\Joel\.nuget\packages\system.objectmodel\4.3.0\ref\netstandard1.3\System.ObjectModel.dll /reference:C:\Users\Joel\.nuget\packages\system.reflection.dispatchproxy\4.3.0\ref\netstandard1.3\System.Reflection.DispatchProxy.dll /reference:C:\Users\Joel\.nuget\packages\system.reflection\4.3.0\ref\netstandard1.5\System.Reflection.dll /reference:C:\Users\Joel\.nuget\packages\system.reflection.extensions\4.3.0\ref\netstandard1.0\System.Reflection.Extensions.dll /reference:C:\Users\Joel\.nuget\packages\system.reflection.metadata\1.4.1\lib\netstandard1.1\System.Reflection.Metadata.dll /reference:C:\Users\Joel\.nuget\packages\system.reflection.primitives\4.3.0\ref\netstandard1.0\System.Reflection.Primitives.dll /reference:C:\Users\Joel\.nuget\packages\system.reflection.typeextensions\4.3.0\ref\netstandard1.5\System.Reflection.TypeExtensions.dll /reference:C:\Users\Joel\.nuget\packages\system.resources.reader\4.3.0\lib\netstandard1.0\System.Resources.Reader.dll /reference:C:\Users\Joel\.nuget\packages\system.resources.resourcemanager\4.3.0\ref\netstandard1.0\System.Resources.ResourceManager.dll /reference:C:\Users\Joel\.nuget\packages\system.runtime\4.3.0\ref\netstandard1.5\System.Runtime.dll /reference:C:\Users\Joel\.nuget\packages\system.runtime.extensions\4.3.0\ref\netstandard1.5\System.Runtime.Extensions.dll /reference:C:\Users\Joel\.nuget\packages\system.runtime.handles\4.3.0\ref\netstandard1.3\System.Runtime.Handles.dll /reference:C:\Users\Joel\.nuget\packages\system.runtime.interopservices\4.3.0\ref\netcoreapp1.1\System.Runtime.InteropServices.dll /reference:C:\Users\Joel\.nuget\packages\system.runtime.interopservices.runtimeinformation\4.3.0\ref\netstandard1.1\System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation.dll /reference:C:\Users\Joel\.nuget\packages\system.runtime.numerics\4.3.0\ref\netstandard1.1\System.Runtime.Numerics.dll /reference:C:\Users\Joel\.nuget\packages\system.security.cryptography.algorithms\4.3.0\ref\netstandard1.6\System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms.dll /reference:C:\Users\Joel\.nuget\packages\system.security.cryptography.encoding\4.3.0\ref\netstandard1.3\System.Security.Cryptography.Encoding.dll /reference:C:\Users\Joel\.nuget\packages\system.security.cryptography.primitives\4.3.0\ref\netstandard1.3\System.Security.Cryptography.Primitives.dll /reference:C:\Users\Joel\.nuget\packages\system.security.cryptography.x509certificates\4.3.0\ref\netstandard1.4\System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.dll /reference:C:\Users\Joel\.nuget\packages\system.security.principal\4.3.0\ref\netstandard1.0\System.Security.Principal.dll /reference:C:\Users\Joel\.nuget\packages\system.text.encoding\4.3.0\ref\netstandard1.3\System.Text.Encoding.dll /reference:C:\Users\Joel\.nuget\packages\system.text.encoding.extensions\4.3.0\ref\netstandard1.3\System.Text.Encoding.Extensions.dll /reference:C:\Users\Joel\.nuget\packages\system.text.regularexpressions\4.3.0\ref\netcoreapp1.1\System.Text.RegularExpressions.dll /reference:C:\Users\Joel\.nuget\packages\system.threading\4.3.0\ref\netstandard1.3\System.Threading.dll /reference:C:\Users\Joel\.nuget\packages\system.threading.tasks.dataflow\4.7.0\lib\netstandard1.1\System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow.dll /reference:C:\Users\Joel\.nuget\packages\system.threading.tasks\4.3.0\ref\netstandard1.3\System.Threading.Tasks.dll /reference:C:\Users\Joel\.nuget\packages\system.threading.tasks.extensions\4.3.0\lib\netstandard1.0\System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions.dll /reference:C:\Users\Joel\.nuget\packages\system.threading.tasks.parallel\4.3.0\ref\netstandard1.1\System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.dll /reference:C:\Users\Joel\.nuget\packages\system.threading.thread\4.3.0\ref\netstandard1.3\System.Threading.Thread.dll /reference:C:\Users\Joel\.nuget\packages\system.threading.threadpool\4.3.0\ref\netstandard1.3\System.Threading.ThreadPool.dll /reference:C:\Users\Joel\.nuget\packages\system.threading.timer\4.3.0\ref\netstandard1.2\System.Threading.Timer.dll /reference:C:\Users\Joel\.nuget\packages\system.xml.readerwriter\4.3.0\ref\netstandard1.3\System.Xml.ReaderWriter.dll /reference:C:\Users\Joel\.nuget\packages\system.xml.xdocument\4.3.0\ref\netstandard1.3\System.Xml.XDocument.dll /debug- /debug:portable /filealign:512 /nologo /optimize+ /out:obj\Release\netcoreapp1.1\win7-x86\ConsoleApp1.dll /ruleset:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Team Tools\Static Analysis Tools\\Rule Sets\MinimumRecommendedRules.ruleset" /target:exe /warnaserror- /utf8output /deterministic+ /analyzer:C:\Users\Joel\.nuget\packages\microsoft.codeanalysis.analyzers\1.1.0\analyzers\dotnet\cs\Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Analyzers.dll /analyzer:C:\Users\Joel\.nuget\packages\microsoft.codeanalysis.analyzers\1.1.0\analyzers\dotnet\cs\Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Analyzers.dll Program.cs "C:\Users\Joel\AppData\Local\Temp\.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.1.AssemblyAttributes.cs" obj\Release\netcoreapp1.1\win7-x86\\TemporaryGeneratedFile_E7A71F73-0F8D-4B9B-B56E-8E70B10BC5D3.cs obj\Release\netcoreapp1.1\win7-x86\\TemporaryGeneratedFile_036C0B5B-1481-4323-8D20-8F5ADCB23D92.cs obj\Release\netcoreapp1.1\win7-x86\\TemporaryGeneratedFile_5937a670-0e60-4077-877b-f7221da3dda1.cs obj\Release\netcoreapp1.1\win7-x86\ConsoleApp1.AssemblyInfo.cs
```

Comment: As I stated in the question we already have the runtime identifiers for our target platforms (Windows10 and Debian), but the publish does not create two sepparate publish folders nor create the native executables.

Comment: @Gusman then the answer is simple: no this is not possible. just like there is no ui for multiple target frameworks.

Comment: that's something you really know or is just an assumption?

Comment: I didnt code Visual studio myself so in that sense its an assumption. But basically if you click the publish UI button in vs2017, a csc.exe command gets executed you can check the logs and see if your runtime is added. But probably for multiple runtimes it summarizes it. (since you can only build for 1 runtime at the time)

Comment: Ok, thanks for the info, I will check the compilation logs.

Comment: @Gusman But i dont get why you want to use the ui, you should use a buildserver for this instead of making release builds on your own system. and there you need a cmd/script anways

Comment: @Gusman I added the command vs2017 uses in my case to execute a publish

Comment: Ok, the scenario is more complex, each developer on the team has a docker with debian, after developing any new feature we have the requirement that before pushing the code to the dev branch it must be test on a Debian environment to avoid any problem with different OS'es, so the build server exists, but for the development and production environments, not for the local tests of each programmer on its own debian docker.

Comment: Joel, update your answer with "no, it can't be done, use dotnet build" or something similar to get a concise answer, I already have accepted this as correct.